# Extracting final word in sentence through regular expression?

Tags: regex

I can't find a way to extract the final word on a line, such as this:

> ^This is a sentence$

I'd like to extract just "sentence". Does someone have an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your sentence literally include ^ and $?

Comment: No, it was just meant to show that it's on a line by itself. Using " (.+)?$" doesn't work, as it takes the second word until the end of the line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the final word is preceded by a space, all you need is:

```
\s(\w+)$
```

The last word in the sentence will then be captured.

Comment: You could also use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or similar, of course.

Comment: `\w` is actually equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (note the underscore). Perhaps adding `-` (hyphen) might be useful for sentences like `This has to be re-evaluated`.

Comment: @slhck Your regex works very well except it also selects the white space before `sentence`. Omitting \s provides the exact result required by OP (extracting only `sentence`). Modification result: `(\w+)$`

Comment: @Ugo True, but the `\s` is outside the match group, so if you take match group results only, there is no difference.

Comment: how about everything except the last word of a sentence?

Comment: @tggagne `(.+)\b\w+$` would do that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
(.*) ([^ ]+)$
```

Replace that with \2 that will give you the last word